# Trouble adding a third TabItem in R shiny

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet

Data

```
df<-structure(list(lon = c(-1.309306062, -1.308591288, -1.308725397, 
-1.308223849, -1.309100942, -1.308788844, -1.309505208, -1.309487017, 
-1.307965425, -1.307626664, -1.309264223, -1.306229451, -1.307167439, 
-1.307846954, -1.308361108, -1.309967322, -1.310144073, -1.310207229, 
-1.310332327, -1.310671738, -1.31180421, -1.311607541, -1.312474199, 
-1.312743518, -1.313056542, -1.312181745, -1.311154382, -1.311484218, 
-1.310989254, -1.312408125, -1.312799476, -1.313737475, -1.314102982, 
-1.313547026, -1.313998781, -1.313728937, -1.313688331, -1.313176409, 
-1.312907533, -1.312342883, -1.31196085, -1.309571159, -1.310019078, 
-1.309446474, -1.310651343, -1.311742706, -1.312701894, -1.313373501, 
-1.312104413, -1.311081217, -1.309651304, -1.309355735, -1.308883116, 
-1.309512252, -1.308505874, -1.307611868, -1.308034561, -1.308878841, 
-1.30959055, -1.306611007, -1.310526938, -1.310785205, -1.31160273, 
-1.311550922, -1.311502941, -1.310709008, -1.309426224, -1.306562029, 
-1.31304945, -1.312303923, -1.309432075, -1.308759213, -1.308113121, 
-1.30921558, -1.30698489, -1.307679453, -1.307993641, -1.308824096, 
-1.309891996, -1.310095431, -1.310615541, -1.31084027, -1.310663799, 
-1.310396993, -1.311282331, -1.312165532, -1.312140463, -1.312682769, 
-1.311926141, -1.311824037, -1.312745885, -1.313058922, -1.313732569, 
-1.314639773, -1.313463089, -1.31279367, -1.308839997, -1.312446898, 
-1.310518884, -1.312237405, -1.313899224, -1.309127168, -1.314035676, 
-1.311071515, -1.31028724, -1.309057883, -1.306676951, -1.307564253, 
-1.30714901, -1.308095356, -1.307645637, -1.307967975, -1.307768975, 
-1.329996387, -1.332834197, -1.330372664, -1.33032833, -1.331746318, 
-1.331257985, -1.333494628, -1.331850567, -1.332551665, -1.331679116, 
-1.331287582, -1.330303341, -1.329878063, -1.329108814, -1.328358002, 
-1.328655294, -1.328379776, -1.328319218, -1.328879225), lat = c(51.76457202, 
51.76488251, 51.76464054, 51.76370376, 51.76375109, 51.76428126, 
51.76481595, 51.76505861, 51.76601172, 51.76636938, 51.76544329, 
51.76676575, 51.76702303, 51.76712594, 51.76667041, 51.76587064, 
51.76568286, 51.76534201, 51.76473989, 51.76433727, 51.76419105, 
51.76365969, 51.76351641, 51.76340532, 51.76378478, 51.76413932, 
51.76499646, 51.76522317, 51.76537312, 51.76545336, 51.76544665, 
51.76570388, 51.76549023, 51.76488457, 51.76471637, 51.76435515, 
51.7641661, 51.76352474, 51.76310058, 51.7630703, 51.76341873, 
51.76334178, 51.76342533, 51.76391649, 51.76567684, 51.7663306, 
51.7661474, 51.76677171, 51.76732175, 51.76790019, 51.76853917, 
51.76891506, 51.76949672, 51.7691048, 51.7685774, 51.76828442, 
51.76812506, 51.76787827, 51.76682149, 51.76645331, 51.76623357, 
51.76354671, 51.7660061, 51.76655426, 51.76685069, 51.76664823, 
51.76714421, 51.76681267, 51.76425228, 51.76277337, 51.76771069, 
51.76812033, 51.76867399, 51.76955262, 51.7675884, 51.76765543, 
51.76700991, 51.76671809, 51.76605901, 51.76507117, 51.76517312, 
51.76468892, 51.76485872, 51.7642997, 51.76420598, 51.76368993, 
51.76399521, 51.76405674, 51.76474922, 51.76574665, 51.76515862, 
51.76553808, 51.76602754, 51.7654484, 51.76468628, 51.76296504, 
51.76377806, 51.76290008, 51.76581093, 51.76619863, 51.76650504, 
51.76395058, 51.76706329, 51.76758544, 51.7686508, 51.76849073, 
51.76593221, 51.76571265, 51.76538652, 51.76509539, 51.7651287, 
51.76489683, 51.7646439, 51.75921563, 51.75639953, 51.75924475, 
51.75892126, 51.75708613, 51.75667003, 51.75680788, 51.75629504, 
51.75689245, 51.75613223, 51.75615698, 51.75598657, 51.75605949, 
51.75615401, 51.75695893, 51.75742817, 51.75744458, 51.75800124, 
51.75795993), nestbox = c("B10", "B100", "B101", "B104", "B107", 
"B109", "B11", "B111", "B116", "B118", "B12", "B121", "B122", 
"B123", "B125", "B129", "B130", "B131", "B133", "B136", "B138", 
"B139", "B140", "B141", "B142", "B147", "B149", "B150", "B151", 
"B153", "B157", "B160", "B161", "B163", "B164", "B165", "B166", 
"B168", "B169", "B170A", "B171", "B173", "B174", "B175", "B176", 
"B177", "B178", "B180", "B183", "B185", "B188", "B189", "B190", 
"B191", "B193", "B194", "B194A", "B195", "B197", "B20", "B200", 
"B203", "B211", "B213", "B214", "B216", "B217", "B22", "B220", 
"B221", "B224", "B225", "B226", "B227", "B228", "B23", "B24", 
"B26", "B29", "B31", "B32", "B33", "B35", "B36", "B37", "B40", 
"B43", "B44", "B49", "B53", "B57", "B58", "B60", "B62A", "B65", 
"B69", "B7", "B70", "B76", "B78", "B79", "B8", "B80A", "B85", 
"B88", "B89", "B93", "B95", "B96", "B97", "B98", "B99", "B99A", 
"C1", "C10", "C101", "C102", "C107", "C108", "C109", "C11", "C110", 
"C111", "C112", "C114", "C115", "C116", "C118", "C120", "C122", 
"C123", "C124"), Species = c("Blue tit", "Blue tit", "Great tit", 
"Great tit", "Blue tit", "Blue tit", "Blue tit", "Blue tit", 
"Great tit", "Great tit", "Blue tit", "Blue tit", "Blue tit", 
"Blue tit", "Blue tit", "Great tit", "Blue tit", "Blue tit", 
"Blue tit", "Blue tit", "Blue tit", "Blue tit", "Blue tit", "Blue tit", 
"Blue tit", "Blue tit", "Blue tit", "Great tit", "Blue tit", 
"Blue tit", "Blue tit", "Blue tit", "Blue tit", "Great tit", 
"Blue tit", "Blue tit", "Nuthatch", "Blue tit", "Great tit", 
"Blue tit", "Great tit", "Blue tit", "Blue tit", "Great tit", 
"Blue tit", "Blue tit", "Blue tit", "Blue tit", "Blue tit", "Blue tit", 
"Great tit", "Blue tit", "Blue tit", "Blue tit", "Great tit", 
"Blue tit", "Great tit", "Marsh tit", "Blue tit", "Great tit", 
"Great tit", "Great tit", "Blue tit", "Great tit", "Blue tit", 
"Great tit", "Great tit", "Blue tit", "Blue tit", "Blue tit", 
"Great tit", "Blue tit", "Blue tit", "Blue tit", "Blue tit", 
"Blue tit", "Great tit", "Blue tit", "Blue tit", "Great tit", 
"Great tit", "Blue tit", "Great tit", "Great tit", "Blue tit", 
"Blue tit", "Great tit", "Great tit", "Great tit", "Blue tit", 
"Great tit", "Great tit", "Blue tit", "Blue tit", "Great tit", 
"Blue tit", "Blue tit", "Blue tit", "Great tit", "Great tit", 
"Great tit", "Great tit", "Blue tit", "Blue tit", "Blue tit", 
"Blue tit", "Blue tit", "Blue tit", "Blue tit", "Blue tit", "Great tit", 
"Blue tit", "Blue tit", "Blue tit", "Great tit", "Blue tit", 
"Blue tit", "Great tit", "Great tit", "Great tit", "Great tit", 
"Blue tit", "Blue tit", "Great tit", "Blue tit", "Great tit", 
"Blue tit", "Great tit", "Blue tit", "Blue tit", "Blue tit", 
"Great tit"), Clutch.size = c(9L, 10L, 9L, 6L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
9L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 8L, 10L, 10L, 9L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 
10L, 7L, 11L, 10L, 11L, 6L, 6L, 9L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 
NA, 9L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 8L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 7L, 9L, 10L, 7L, 7L, 
8L, 10L, 12L, 10L, 7L, 8L, 6L, 8L, 7L, NA, 10L, 8L, 8L, 10L, 
NA, 7L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 8L, 10L, 8L, NA, 12L, 11L, 8L, 8L, 5L, 6L, 
6L, 1L, 1L, 9L, 7L, 7L, 10L, 6L, 8L, 8L, 8L, NA, 8L, 9L, 6L, 
1L, 8L, 11L, 7L, 7L, 8L, NA, 9L, 8L, 7L, 8L, 10L, 8L, 10L, 7L, 
7L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 7L, 11L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 6L, 4L, 8L, NA, 10L, 
7L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 8L, 2L), April.lay.date = c(24L, 18L, 17L, 
39L, 17L, 16L, 18L, 21L, 30L, 17L, 21L, 17L, 18L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 
17L, 20L, 21L, 25L, 21L, 26L, 20L, 25L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 40L, 24L, 
24L, 23L, 19L, 19L, 15L, 22L, 18L, NA, 19L, 23L, 22L, 20L, 21L, 
23L, 16L, 17L, 24L, 26L, 19L, 22L, 21L, 24L, 20L, 18L, 14L, 10L, 
23L, 19L, 9L, 20L, 19L, NA, 13L, 17L, 14L, 20L, NA, 26L, 18L, 
21L, 25L, 18L, 19L, 19L, NA, 19L, 20L, 18L, 20L, 25L, 24L, 26L, 
25L, 40L, 18L, 22L, 21L, 11L, 20L, 17L, 20L, 16L, NA, 22L, 17L, 
24L, 20L, 20L, 21L, 38L, 20L, 33L, NA, 41L, 24L, 16L, 18L, 18L, 
26L, 13L, 21L, 17L, 13L, 16L, 16L, 26L, 16L, 34L, 16L, 10L, 15L, 
10L, 1L, 14L, NA, 12L, 10L, 8L, 14L, 16L, 13L, 18L, 20L), April.hatch.date = c(45L, 
NA, 39L, 54L, 37L, 36L, 37L, 42L, 48L, 44L, NA, 37L, 41L, 42L, 
44L, 44L, 39L, 42L, 45L, 50L, 41L, 48L, 43L, 44L, 38L, 39L, 44L, 
57L, 45L, 46L, 46L, 41L, 39L, 37L, 43L, 40L, NA, 41L, 43L, 46L, 
42L, 41L, 43L, 38L, 38L, 46L, 46L, 41L, 46L, 40L, 42L, 41L, 37L, 
36L, 32L, 41L, NA, 29L, 39L, 39L, NA, 36L, 38L, 34L, 43L, NA, 
46L, 41L, 45L, NA, 39L, 39L, 38L, NA, 40L, 41L, 39L, 40L, NA, 
41L, NA, NA, NA, 38L, NA, 44L, 33L, 40L, 40L, 42L, 37L, NA, 42L, 
39L, 46L, NA, 41L, 44L, 56L, 41L, 50L, NA, 52L, 43L, 34L, 37L, 
NA, 47L, 36L, 39L, 36L, 34L, NA, 37L, 44L, 39L, 52L, 34L, 28L, 
35L, 29L, NA, 34L, NA, 34L, 29L, 35L, 35L, 40L, 35L, 39L, NA), 
    Lay.date = c("24-04-2022", "18-04-2022", "17-04-2022", "09-05-2022", 
    "17-04-2022", "16-04-2022", "18-04-2022", "21-04-2022", "30-04-2022", 
    "17-04-2022", "21-04-2022", "17-04-2022", "18-04-2022", "21-04-2022", 
    "22-04-2022", "23-04-2022", "17-04-2022", "20-04-2022", "21-04-2022", 
    "25-04-2022", "21-04-2022", "26-04-2022", "20-04-2022", "25-04-2022", 
    "16-04-2022", "17-04-2022", "18-04-2022", "10-05-2022", "24-04-2022", 
    "24-04-2022", "23-04-2022", "19-04-2022", "19-04-2022", "15-04-2022", 
    "22-04-2022", "18-04-2022", "", "19-04-2022", "23-04-2022", 
    "22-04-2022", "20-04-2022", "21-04-2022", "23-04-2022", "16-04-2022", 
    "17-04-2022", "24-04-2022", "26-04-2022", "19-04-2022", "22-04-2022", 
    "21-04-2022", "24-04-2022", "20-04-2022", "18-04-2022", "14-04-2022", 
    "10-04-2022", "23-04-2022", "19-04-2022", "09-04-2022", "20-04-2022", 
    "19-04-2022", "", "13-04-2022", "17-04-2022", "14-04-2022", 
    "20-04-2022", "", "26-04-2022", "18-04-2022", "21-04-2022", 
    "25-04-2022", "18-04-2022", "19-04-2022", "19-04-2022", "", 
    "19-04-2022", "20-04-2022", "18-04-2022", "20-04-2022", "25-04-2022", 
    "24-04-2022", "26-04-2022", "25-04-2022", "10-05-2022", "18-04-2022", 
    "22-04-2022", "21-04-2022", "11-04-2022", "20-04-2022", "17-04-2022", 
    "20-04-2022", "16-04-2022", "", "22-04-2022", "17-04-2022", 
    "24-04-2022", "20-04-2022", "20-04-2022", "21-04-2022", "08-05-2022", 
    "20-04-2022", "03-05-2022", "", "11-05-2022", "24-04-2022", 
    "16-04-2022", "18-04-2022", "18-04-2022", "26-04-2022", "13-04-2022", 
    "21-04-2022", "17-04-2022", "13-04-2022", "16-04-2022", "16-04-2022", 
    "26-04-2022", "16-04-2022", "04-05-2022", "16-04-2022", "10-04-2022", 
    "15-04-2022", "10-04-2022", "01-04-2022", "14-04-2022", "", 
    "12-04-2022", "10-04-2022", "08-04-2022", "14-04-2022", "16-04-2022", 
    "13-04-2022", "18-04-2022", "20-04-2022"), Hatch.date = c("15-05-2022", 
    "", "09-05-2022", "24-05-2022", "07-05-2022", "06-05-2022", 
    "07-05-2022", "12-05-2022", "18-05-2022", "14-05-2022", "", 
    "07-05-2022", "11-05-2022", "12-05-2022", "14-05-2022", "14-05-2022", 
    "09-05-2022", "12-05-2022", "15-05-2022", "20-05-2022", "11-05-2022", 
    "18-05-2022", "13-05-2022", "14-05-2022", "08-05-2022", "09-05-2022", 
    "14-05-2022", "27-05-2022", "15-05-2022", "16-05-2022", "16-05-2022", 
    "11-05-2022", "09-05-2022", "07-05-2022", "13-05-2022", "10-05-2022", 
    "", "11-05-2022", "13-05-2022", "16-05-2022", "12-05-2022", 
    "11-05-2022", "13-05-2022", "08-05-2022", "08-05-2022", "16-05-2022", 
    "16-05-2022", "11-05-2022", "16-05-2022", "10-05-2022", "12-05-2022", 
    "11-05-2022", "07-05-2022", "06-05-2022", "02-05-2022", "11-05-2022", 
    "", "29-04-2022", "09-05-2022", "09-05-2022", "", "06-05-2022", 
    "08-05-2022", "04-05-2022", "13-05-2022", "", "16-05-2022", 
    "11-05-2022", "15-05-2022", "", "09-05-2022", "09-05-2022", 
    "08-05-2022", "", "10-05-2022", "11-05-2022", "09-05-2022", 
    "10-05-2022", "", "11-05-2022", "", "", "", "08-05-2022", 
    "", "14-05-2022", "03-05-2022", "10-05-2022", "10-05-2022", 
    "12-05-2022", "07-05-2022", "", "12-05-2022", "09-05-2022", 
    "16-05-2022", "", "11-05-2022", "14-05-2022", "26-05-2022", 
    "11-05-2022", "20-05-2022", "", "22-05-2022", "13-05-2022", 
    "04-05-2022", "07-05-2022", "", "17-05-2022", "06-05-2022", 
    "09-05-2022", "06-05-2022", "04-05-2022", "", "07-05-2022", 
    "14-05-2022", "09-05-2022", "22-05-2022", "04-05-2022", "28-04-2022", 
    "05-05-2022", "29-04-2022", "", "04-05-2022", "", "04-05-2022", 
    "29-04-2022", "05-05-2022", "05-05-2022", "10-05-2022", "05-05-2022", 
    "09-05-2022", ""), Num.fledglings = c(0L, 0L, 7L, 0L, 9L, 
    8L, 8L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 0L, 6L, 3L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 9L, 5L, 5L, 0L, 
    8L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 11L, 9L, 4L, 2L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 8L, 8L, 4L, 
    9L, 9L, 0L, 8L, 6L, 4L, 3L, 7L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 
    6L, 0L, 0L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 6L, 0L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 0L, 10L, 8L, 
    7L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 8L, 5L, 0L, 3L, 3L, 8L, 7L, 
    0L, 6L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 9L, 0L, 4L, 10L, 6L, 8L, 6L, 6L, 0L, 
    8L, 9L, 0L, 0L, 8L, 5L, 0L, 4L, 3L, 0L, 6L, 0L, 7L, 4L, 0L, 
    3L, 7L, 5L, 7L, 8L, 0L, 9L, 6L, 9L, 6L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 3L, 0L, 
    8L, 0L, 9L, 6L, 6L, 0L, 10L, 11L, 0L, 0L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-132L), class = "data.frame")
```

This is my first shiny App so it's a bit of a mess layout wise, but I am trying to add another sidebar tab which will bring users to another leaflet map. But I just can't see why it isn't working, I've been at it for hours.
The tab "Clutch size across Wytham" is the issue, any pointers appreciated.
Some of the outputs may look a bit strange as I've had to drastically reduce the size of the dataframe so that I could provide an example

```
spcol<-colorFactor(palette = "viridis", broods2022$Species)
eggcol<-colorFactor(palette = "viridis", broods2022$Clutch.size )

################### UI ###############################


ui <- dashboardPage(
  
  #### Title ####
  
  dashboardHeader(title = "Breeding Season 2022", titleWidth = 200),
  
  
  #### Sidebar ##### 
  
  dashboardSidebar(
    #### sidebar menu ####    
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem("Home", tabName = "dashboard", icon = icon("fa-bird")),
      menuItem("Laydate & Hatchdate", icon = icon("th"), tabName = "Laydate"),
      menuItem("Clutch size across Wytham",
               icon = icon("fa-solid fa-egg", lib = "font-awesome"), tabName = "ClutchMap")
      
      
      
    )
  ),
  
  
  
  ##### Dashboard Body ######
  dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
      #first tab
      tabItem(
        tabName = "dashboard",
        #### fluid row 1 Info  ####        
        fluidRow(
          strong(h1("Map of Wytham Woods and nest boxes", align = "center")),
          p(h4("Below is some information about the numbers of nests built 
        (though these won't all have contained eggs), also about average clutch sizes, both for the most recent breeding
         season and the historical average.")),
          p(h4("Choosing a species from the drop down menu below will show the nest boxes for that species on the map. 
           You can also view the boxes which were unoccupied. Clicking on any box will display some information about that box" ))
        ),
        
        ##### Fluid row 2 Nest Numbers ######
        fluidRow(
          infoBoxOutput('GretiNest', width = 3), #make info boxes with no of nests
          infoBoxOutput("BlutiNest", width = 3),
          infoBoxOutput("MartiNest", width = 3),
          infoBoxOutput("CoatiNest", width = 3)
        ),
        ##### fluid Row 3 CLutch Size ino ####
        fluidRow(
          infoBoxOutput("GretiEggs", width = 3), #make info boxes with mean clutch size
          infoBoxOutput("BlutiEggs", width = 3),
          infoBoxOutput("MartiEggs", width = 3),
          infoBoxOutput("CoatiEggs", width = 3)
        ),
        ##### fluid row 4 Map
        fluidRow(
          title ="Map of Wytham",
          sidebarLayout(
            sidebarPanel(
              selectInput("Species", label = "Species", choices = unique(df$Species), selected = "Great tit")
            ),
            mainPanel(
              leafletOutput("NestMap", width = "900px", height = "700px"))),
          
          
          
        )
      ),
      
      
      ##### Tab item 2 Laydate and hatchdate ########
      tabItem(tabName = "Laydate",
              plotOutput("laydate22"),
              plotOutput("hatchdate22")
      ),
      
      tabItem(
        selectInput("ClutchSp", label = "Species", 
                    choices = unique(df$Species), 
                    selected = "Great tit"),
        
        tabName = "ClutchMap",
        leafletOutput("Cmap", width = "900px", height = "700px"),
        selectInput("ClutchSp", label = "Species", 
                    choices = unique(df$Species), 
                    selected = "Great tit"),
        
        
        
        
        
        
      )
    )
    
    
    
    
  )
  
  
  
)





######################## SERVER ######################################

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  
  ##### Output 1 Nest numbers outputs ####
  output$GretiNest<- renderInfoBox({
    
    
    GretiNest<- df %>% #clean data to produce count of no of nests
      group_by(Species) %>%
      summarise(count = n())
    
    Greti<- GretiNest[3,2]
    infoBox("Great tit Nests", Greti, icon = icon("feather"),  color = "green")
    
    
  })
  output$BlutiNest<- renderInfoBox({
    
    GretiNest<- df %>%
      group_by(Species) %>%
      summarise(count = n())
    Bluti<- GretiNest[1,2]
    infoBox("Blue tit Nests", Bluti, icon = icon("feather"),  color = "aqua")
    
  })
  output$MartiNest<- renderInfoBox({
    GretiNest<- df %>%
      group_by(Species) %>%
      summarise(count = n())
    
    Marti<- GretiNest[4,2]
    infoBox("Marsh tit Nests", Marti, icon = icon("feather"),  color = "teal")
    
  })
  output$CoatiNest<- renderInfoBox({
    GretiNest<- df %>%
      group_by(Species) %>%
      summarise(count = n())
    
    Coati<- GretiNest[2,2]
    infoBox("Coal tit Nests", Coati, icon = icon("feather"),  color = "black") 
  })
  
  
  

    
 
  ##### Output 3 Map#####  
  output$NestMap <- renderLeaflet({
    
    
    
    leaflet() %>% addTiles() %>% 
      setView(lng = -1.324640, lat = 51.770462, zoom = 14) %>%
      addCircleMarkers(lng = df$lon, lat = df$lat, color = spcol(df$Species), radius = 5,
                       stroke = F, fillOpacity = 1,
                       popup = paste("<h6>Nest box info</h6>","Name:",
                                     df$nestbox, "<br>", "Laydate:", 
                                     df$Lay.date, "<br>", "Clutch Size:",
                                     df$Clutch.size,"<br>",
                                     "Hatch Date:", df$Hatch.date,"<br>",
                                     "No. of Fledged Chicks:", df$Num.fledglings,  sep = " ") )
    
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$Species, {
    
    if(input$Species != "")
    {
      leafletProxy("NestMap") %>% clearShapes() %>% clearMarkers()
      index = which(df$Species == input$Species)
      leafletProxy("NestMap")%>%  
        addCircleMarkers(lng = df$lon[index], lat = df$lat[index],color = spcol(df$Species[index]),
                         radius = 5, stroke = F, fillOpacity = 1,
                         popup = paste("<h6>Nest box info</h6>","Name:", df$nestbox[index], "<br>", "Laydate:", df$Lay.date[index], "<br>", "Clutch Size:", df$Clutch.size[index],
                                       "<br>",
                                       "Hatch Date:", df$Hatch.date[index], "<br>", "No. of Fledged Chicks:", df$Num.fledglings[index], sep = " "))
    }
  })
  ##### Lay date and Hatchdate plots#####  
  output$laydate22 <- renderPlot({
    df %>%
      ggplot(aes(April.lay.date, fill = Species)) + geom_bar() +
      scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0,70),breaks = seq(0,70, by = 10)) +
      ggtitle("Laydate 2022") +
      theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))+
      xlab("April Lay Date (days since April 1st)")+
      ylab("No. of Nests")+
      theme_classic()
    
  })
  output$hatchdate22<- renderPlot({
    df %>%
      ggplot(aes(April.hatch.date, fill = Species)) + geom_bar() +
      scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0,70),breaks = seq(0,70, by = 10)) +
      ggtitle("Hatchdate 2022") +
      theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))+
      xlab("April Hatch Date (days since April 1st)")+
      ylab("No. of Nests")+
      theme_classic() 
  })
  
  output$CMap <- renderLeaflet({
    
    leaflet() %>% addTiles() %>% 
      setView(lng = -1.324640, lat = 51.770462, zoom = 14) %>%
      addCircleMarkers(lng = df$lon, lat = df$lat, color = eggcol(df$Clutch.size), radius = 5,
                       stroke = F, fillOpacity = 1,
                       popup = paste("<h6>Nest box info</h6>","Name:",
                                     df$nestbox, "<br>", "Laydate:", 
                                     df$Lay.date, "<br>", "Clutch Size:",
                                     df$Clutch.size,"<br>",
                                     "Hatch Date:", df$Hatch.date,"<br>",
                                     "No. of Fledged Chicks:",
                                     df$Num.fledglings,  sep = " ")
      )%>%
      addLegend('bottomright', pal = eggcol, values = df$Clutch.size,
                title = 'Clutch Size',
                opacity = 2)
    
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$ClutchSp, {
    
    if(input$ClutchSp != "")
    {
      leafletProxy("CMap") %>% clearShapes() %>% clearMarkers()
      index = which(df$Clutch.size == input$ClutchSp)
      leafletProxy("CMap")%>%  
        addCircleMarkers(lng = df$lon[index], 
                         lat = df$lat[index],
                         color = eggcol(df$Clutch.size[index]),
                         radius = 5, stroke = F, fillOpacity = 1,
                         popup = paste("<h6>Nest box info</h6>","Name:",
                                       df$nestbox[index],
                                       "<br>", "Laydate:",
                                       df$Lay.date[index], "<br>", "Clutch Size:", df$Clutch.size[index],
                                       "<br>",
                                       "Hatch Date:",
                                       df$Hatch.date[index], 
                                       "<br>", "No. of Fledged Chicks:",
                                       df$Num.fledglings[index], sep = " "))
    }
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Have edited to put parentheses in correct place as per @hailey below.

Comment: Found another typo. Problem solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
spcol<-colorFactor(palette = "viridis", broods2022$Species)
eggcol<-colorFactor(palette = "viridis", broods2022$Clutch.size )

################### UI ###############################


ui <- dashboardPage(
  
  #### Title ####
  
  dashboardHeader(title = "Breeding Season 2022", titleWidth = 200),
  
  
  #### Sidebar ##### 
  
  dashboardSidebar(
    #### sidebar menu ####    
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem("Home", tabName = "dashboard", icon = icon("fa-bird")),
      menuItem("Laydate & Hatchdate", icon = icon("th"), tabName = "Laydate"),
      menuItem("Clutch size across Wytham",
               icon = icon("fa-solid fa-egg", lib = "font-awesome"), tabName = "ClutchMap")
      
      
      
    )
  ),
  
  
  
  ##### Dashboard Body ######
  dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
      #first tab
      tabItem(
        tabName = "dashboard",
        #### fluid row 1 Info  ####        
        fluidRow(
          strong(h1("Map of Wytham Woods and nest boxes", align = "center")),
          p(h4("Below is some information about the numbers of nests built 
        (though these won't all have contained eggs), also about average clutch sizes, both for the most recent breeding
         season and the historical average.")),
          p(h4("Choosing a species from the drop down menu below will show the nest boxes for that species on the map. 
           You can also view the boxes which were unoccupied. Clicking on any box will display some information about that box" ))
        ),
        
        ##### Fluid row 2 Nest Numbers ######
        fluidRow(
          infoBoxOutput('GretiNest', width = 3), #make info boxes with no of nests
          infoBoxOutput("BlutiNest", width = 3),
          infoBoxOutput("MartiNest", width = 3),
          infoBoxOutput("CoatiNest", width = 3)
        ),
        ##### fluid Row 3 CLutch Size ino ####
        fluidRow(
          infoBoxOutput("GretiEggs", width = 3), #make info boxes with mean clutch size
          infoBoxOutput("BlutiEggs", width = 3),
          infoBoxOutput("MartiEggs", width = 3),
          infoBoxOutput("CoatiEggs", width = 3)
        ),
        ##### fluid row 4 Map
        fluidRow(
          title ="Map of Wytham",
          sidebarLayout(
            sidebarPanel(
              selectInput("Species", label = "Species", choices = unique(df$Species), selected = "Great tit")
            ),
            mainPanel(
              leafletOutput("NestMap", width = "900px", height = "700px"))),
          
          
          
        )
      ),
      
      
      ##### Tab item 2 Laydate and hatchdate ########
      tabItem(tabName = "Laydate",
              plotOutput("laydate22"),
              plotOutput("hatchdate22")
      ),
      
      tabItem(
        selectInput("ClutchSp", label = "Species", 
                    choices = unique(df$Species), 
                    selected = "Great tit"),
        
        tabName = "ClutchMap",
        leafletOutput("Cmap", width = "900px", height = "700px"),
        selectInput("ClutchSp", label = "Species", 
                    choices = unique(df$Species), 
                    selected = "Great tit"),
        
        
        
        
        
        
      )
    )
    
    
    
    
  )
  
  
  
)





######################## SERVER ######################################

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  
  ##### Output 1 Nest numbers outputs ####
  output$GretiNest<- renderInfoBox({
    
    
    GretiNest<- df %>% #clean data to produce count of no of nests
      group_by(Species) %>%
      summarise(count = n())
    
    Greti<- GretiNest[3,2]
    infoBox("Great tit Nests", Greti, icon = icon("feather"),  color = "green")
    
    
  })
  output$BlutiNest<- renderInfoBox({
    
    GretiNest<- df %>%
      group_by(Species) %>%
      summarise(count = n())
    Bluti<- GretiNest[1,2]
    infoBox("Blue tit Nests", Bluti, icon = icon("feather"),  color = "aqua")
    
  })
  output$MartiNest<- renderInfoBox({
    GretiNest<- df %>%
      group_by(Species) %>%
      summarise(count = n())
    
    Marti<- GretiNest[4,2]
    infoBox("Marsh tit Nests", Marti, icon = icon("feather"),  color = "teal")
    
  })
  output$CoatiNest<- renderInfoBox({
    GretiNest<- df %>%
      group_by(Species) %>%
      summarise(count = n())
    
    Coati<- GretiNest[2,2]
    infoBox("Coal tit Nests", Coati, icon = icon("feather"),  color = "black") 
  })
  
  
  

    
 
  ##### Output 3 Map#####  
  output$NestMap <- renderLeaflet({
    
    
    
    leaflet() %>% addTiles() %>% 
      setView(lng = -1.324640, lat = 51.770462, zoom = 14) %>%
      addCircleMarkers(lng = df$lon, lat = df$lat, color = spcol(df$Species), radius = 5,
                       stroke = F, fillOpacity = 1,
                       popup = paste("<h6>Nest box info</h6>","Name:",
                                     df$nestbox, "<br>", "Laydate:", 
                                     df$Lay.date, "<br>", "Clutch Size:",
                                     df$Clutch.size,"<br>",
                                     "Hatch Date:", df$Hatch.date,"<br>",
                                     "No. of Fledged Chicks:", df$Num.fledglings,  sep = " ") )
    
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$Species, {
    
    if(input$Species != "")
    {
      leafletProxy("NestMap") %>% clearShapes() %>% clearMarkers()
      index = which(df$Species == input$Species)
      leafletProxy("NestMap")%>%  
        addCircleMarkers(lng = df$lon[index], lat = df$lat[index],color = spcol(df$Species[index]),
                         radius = 5, stroke = F, fillOpacity = 1,
                         popup = paste("<h6>Nest box info</h6>","Name:", df$nestbox[index], "<br>", "Laydate:", df$Lay.date[index], "<br>", "Clutch Size:", df$Clutch.size[index],
                                       "<br>",
                                       "Hatch Date:", df$Hatch.date[index], "<br>", "No. of Fledged Chicks:", df$Num.fledglings[index], sep = " "))
    }
  })
  ##### Lay date and Hatchdate plots#####  
  output$laydate22 <- renderPlot({
    df %>%
      ggplot(aes(April.lay.date, fill = Species)) + geom_bar() +
      scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0,70),breaks = seq(0,70, by = 10)) +
      ggtitle("Laydate 2022") +
      theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))+
      xlab("April Lay Date (days since April 1st)")+
      ylab("No. of Nests")+
      theme_classic()
    
  })
  output$hatchdate22<- renderPlot({
    df %>%
      ggplot(aes(April.hatch.date, fill = Species)) + geom_bar() +
      scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0,70),breaks = seq(0,70, by = 10)) +
      ggtitle("Hatchdate 2022") +
      theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))+
      xlab("April Hatch Date (days since April 1st)")+
      ylab("No. of Nests")+
      theme_classic() 
  })
  
  output$Cmap <- renderLeaflet({
    
    leaflet() %>% addTiles() %>% 
      setView(lng = -1.324640, lat = 51.770462, zoom = 14) %>%
      addCircleMarkers(lng = df$lon, lat = df$lat, color = eggcol(df$Clutch.size), radius = 5,
                       stroke = F, fillOpacity = 1,
                       popup = paste("<h6>Nest box info</h6>","Name:",
                                     df$nestbox, "<br>", "Laydate:", 
                                     df$Lay.date, "<br>", "Clutch Size:",
                                     df$Clutch.size,"<br>",
                                     "Hatch Date:", df$Hatch.date,"<br>",
                                     "No. of Fledged Chicks:",
                                     df$Num.fledglings,  sep = " ")
      )%>%
      addLegend('bottomright', pal = eggcol, values = df$Clutch.size,
                title = 'Clutch Size',
                opacity = 2)
    
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$ClutchSp, {
    
    if(input$ClutchSp != "")
    {
      leafletProxy("Cmap") %>% clearShapes() %>% clearMarkers()
      index = which(df$Clutch.size == input$ClutchSp)
      leafletProxy("Cmap")%>%  
        addCircleMarkers(lng = df$lon[index], 
                         lat = df$lat[index],
                         color = eggcol(df$Clutch.size[index]),
                         radius = 5, stroke = F, fillOpacity = 1,
                         popup = paste("<h6>Nest box info</h6>","Name:",
                                       df$nestbox[index],
                                       "<br>", "Laydate:",
                                       df$Lay.date[index], "<br>", "Clutch Size:", df$Clutch.size[index],
                                       "<br>",
                                       "Hatch Date:",
                                       df$Hatch.date[index], 
                                       "<br>", "No. of Fledged Chicks:",
                                       df$Num.fledglings[index], sep = " "))
    }
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

The name of the outputs for the second map did not match.

Answer (score 1):

You put the parentheses for the tab "Clutch size across Wytham" in the wrong spot. Here's the corrected line:

```
menuItem("Clutch size across Wytham", icon = icon("fa-solid fa-egg", lib ="font-awesome"), tabName = "ClutchMap")
```

Comment: Thanks for noticing that @hailey, did it run correctly for you? for me the map still doesn't appear